# Can't $unwind documents after $group

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm learning Mongo and I'm not understanding something about the aggregate function. I have a User that can make many different kinds of posts, I match the user by blogName and then $lookup all posts that have the matching user ID.

After that I'm stumped. If I unwind and don't group then I get the mess of joined documents, but all I want are the posts.

If I group after $unwind then the documents are turned back into objects.

This code:

```
return User
          .aggregate([
            { 
              $match: { 
                blogName: blogName 
              } 
            },
            {
              $lookup: {
                from: 'posts',
                localField: '_id',
                foreignField: 'user',
                as: 'posts'
              }
            },
            {
              $unwind: "$posts"
            },
            {
              $group: {
                _id: "$_id",
                'posts': { $push: { fields: '$posts' } }
              }
            },
```

Gives me this:

```
[
   {
     _id: 6065e579bf709d81274cc51e,
     posts: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
   }
]
```

Adding a second `$unwind` after `$group` just gives me this:

```
[
   { _id: 6065e579bf709d81274cc51e, posts: { fields: [Object] } },
   { _id: 6065e579bf709d81274cc51e, posts: { fields: [Object] } },
   { _id: 6065e579bf709d81274cc51e, posts: { fields: [Object] } },
   { _id: 6065e579bf709d81274cc51e, posts: { fields: [Object] } }
]
```

Which is further from what I want.

I just want the posts. If I can $unwind the posts in this array then I can handle everything from there. What am I not understanding about this?

Update 1:

If I just use $project like so:

```
return User
          .aggregate([
            { 
              $match: { 
                blogName: blogName 
              } 
            },
            {
              $lookup: {
                from: 'posts',
                localField: '_id',
                foreignField: 'user',
                as: 'posts'
              }
            },
            {
              $unwind: "$posts"
            },
            {
              $project: {
                "_id": 0,
                "posts": "$posts"
              }
            },
```

I can get this array:

```
[
  {
    posts: {
       _id: 60664856447970128fee597b,
       descriptionImages: [],
       tags: [],
       likes: [],
       kind: 'TextPost',
       createdAt: 2021-04-01T22:25:26.531Z,
       updatedAt: 2021-04-01T22:25:26.531Z,
       title: '',
       body: '',
       user: 6065e579bf709d81274cc51e,
       __v: 0
    }
  },
  {
    posts: {
      _id: 60664925d2548912dc960e05,
      mainImages: [],
      descriptionImages: [],
      tags: [],
      likes: [],
      kind: 'PhotoPost',
      createdAt: 2021-04-01T22:28:53.179Z,
      updatedAt: 2021-04-01T22:28:53.179Z,
      user: 6065e579bf709d81274cc51e,
      description: '',
      __v: 0
    }
  },
  {
    posts: {
      _id: 6066495f347bb812fd6dc703,
      mainImages: [],
      descriptionImages: [],
      tags: [],
      likes: [],
      kind: 'PhotoPost',
      createdAt: 2021-04-01T22:29:51.815Z,
      updatedAt: 2021-04-01T22:29:51.815Z,
      user: 6065e579bf709d81274cc51e,
      description: '',
      __v: 0
    }
  },
  {
    posts: {
      _id: 60664961347bb812fd6dc704,
      descriptionImages: [],
      tags: [],
      likes: [],
      kind: 'TextPost',
      createdAt: 2021-04-01T22:29:53.385Z,
      updatedAt: 2021-04-01T22:29:53.385Z,
      title: '',
      body: '',
      user: 6065e579bf709d81274cc51e,
      __v: 0
    }
  }
]
```

But now I'm stumped as to how to get rid of the extra level of nesting. I just need each post object without the additional nesting under posts.

Comment: Please add sample data, and share https://mongoplayground.net/ link

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/bCwBJipyYYZ

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { blogName: "abc" } },
  { $unwind: "$posts" },
  { $replaceRoot: { "newRoot": "$posts" } }
])
```

Use [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot)

> Replaces the input document with the specified document. The operation replaces all existing fields in the input document, including the _id field. You can promote an existing embedded document to the top level, or create a new document for promotion (see example).

---

```
User.aggregate([
    { $match: {  blogName: blogName } },
    { $lookup: { from: 'posts', localField: '_id', foreignField: 'user', as: 'posts' } },
    { $unwind: "$posts" },
    { $replaceRoot: { "newRoot": "$posts" } }
 ]
```